# Incorrect cell information being pushed to next view controller

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So currently I have a table view: 
[image]

When I click on a cell, occasionally, it will give incorrect info about the event. For example, here is when I add an extra event

[image]

When I click on this new event, it gives the wrong info, and instead gives the info for the "testing" event. Each name in the cell represents one event, which has info such as registered . users, time of event, ect. When I click on asfe, the info given is the one corresponding with testing. This bug happens everyonce in a while and i dont know what is causing it.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
class AdminEvents{
    var eventName:String?
    var eventDesc:String?
    var eventStartDate:String?
    var eventEndDate:String?
    var numPeople:Int?
    var numRegister:Int?

    init(evName:String, evDesc:String, evStartDate:String, evEndDate:String, evNumPeople:Int, evNumRegistered:Int){
        self.eventName = evName
        self.eventDesc = evDesc
        self.eventStartDate = evStartDate
        self.eventEndDate = evEndDate
        self.numPeople = evNumPeople
        self.numRegister = evNumRegistered
    }
}

class AdminsEventsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var eventsArray = [String]()
    var actualEvents:[AdminEvents] = []




    @IBOutlet weak var tblEvents: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let id = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
         Database.database().reference().child("users").child(id!).child("createdEvents").observe(.value) { snapshot in
                 //self.eventsArray.removeAll()
               print("start")
               print(snapshot.childrenCount)
               let enumerator = snapshot.children
               while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
                   self.eventsArray.append(rest.key as! String)
               }
                      Database.database().reference().child("Events").observe(.value) { (data) in
                           let events = data.value as! [String:[String:Any]]
                           for(_,value) in events{
                               print(self.eventsArray)
                               if(self.eventsArray.contains(value["EventName"]! as! String)){
                                   self.actualEvents.append(AdminEvents(evName: value["EventName"]! as! String, evDesc: value["EventDescription"]! as! String, evStartDate: value["start time"]! as! String, evEndDate: value["end time"] as! String, evNumPeople: value["NumberOfPeople"]! as! Int, evNumRegistered: value["currentPeople"] as! Int))
                                  }
                               }
                               print("Actual events array " + "\(self.actualEvents)")
                         }
                       self.tblEvents.reloadData()
                   }
                  self.tblEvents.dataSource = self
                  self.tblEvents.delegate = self

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("count: "  + "\(eventsArray.count)")
          return eventsArray.count
      }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "productstable", for: indexPath)
          cell.textLabel?.text = self.eventsArray[indexPath.row]
          return cell
      }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
           if let destination = segue.destination as? RegisteredUsersViewController {
               destination.events = actualEvents[(tblEvents.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
               tblEvents.deselectRow(at: tblEvents.indexPathForSelectedRow!, animated: true)

           }
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

You can see that in the prepare method, I am pushing the event name to the next view controller.

This the firebase structure
[image]

Edit: Someone was asking what is being pushed in the segue, and I forgot to add the class that has this.

```
class AdminEvents{
var eventName:String?
var eventDesc:String?
var eventStartDate:String?
var eventEndDate:String?
var numPeople:Int?
var numRegister:Int?

init(evName:String, evDesc:String, evStartDate:String, evEndDate:String, evNumPeople:Int, evNumRegistered:Int){
    self.eventName = evName
    self.eventDesc = evDesc
    self.eventStartDate = evStartDate
    self.eventEndDate = evEndDate
    self.numPeople = evNumPeople
    self.numRegister = evNumRegistered
}
```

}

Comment: Your table view is driven by `actualUsers` but your segue uses `events`.  Where do you set the `events` property?

Comment: I added an edit that shows the AdminEvents class. Let me know if it is still confusing

Comment: That’s the class but where do you assign an instance of that class to the `events` property that you use in the segue? Your problem is that sometimes this property doesn’t have the value that you want it to have, so sometimes you haven’t assigned the right value to it. Where do you do that assignment?

Comment: ok so that was my mistake, I meant to post some other code. So you can see here that destination.events is being assigned value

Comment: Presumably you have an `action` segue attached to your cell. This is your problem. It is not guaranteed that the row selection state will be correct when the segue triggers. You can either implement `didSelectRow` and trigger the segue programmatically or use the `sender` passed to `prepare`; it will be the cell that was tapped and you can use `indexPathForCell` to map that back to a row.

Comment: could u give that example in code, im not sure what you mean. Im not very experienced in swift

Answer (score 1):

In your `prepare(for:sender:)` function you are assuming that the table row selection value is the cell that triggered the segue, but this is not guaranteed.

It is safer to use the `sender` parameter to identify the row that was tapped:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? RegisteredUsersViewController, 
       let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell, 
       let indexPath = tblEvents.indexPath(for:cell) {
               destination.events = actualEvents[indexPath.row]
               tblEvents.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
           }
    }
}
```